# jquery ajax $.post not working IE10

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer, post, internet-explorer-10

I've tried this two ways.

Way 1

```js
function Login() {
    var email = encodeURIComponent($("#loginemail").val());
    var pass = encodeURIComponent($("#password").val());
    $.ajax({
        url:"/user/login",
        type: "POST",
        data: {email:email, password:pass},
        dataType: "json"
    }).done(LoginDone);
    //$.post("/user/login", {email:email, password:pass}, LoginDone);
}
```

Way 2

```
    function Login() {
        var email = encodeURIComponent($("#loginemail").val());
        var pass = encodeURIComponent($("#password").val());
        $.post("/user/login", {email:email, password:pass}, LoginDone);
    }
```

Both ways work fine on chrome, but for some reason with IE it doesn't send the data `{email:email, password:pass}` in the `POST`, or at all.

I've tried both on a local server, and on a live webserver, both with the same results.

Using IE10 here.

Comment: This will be a hard one to troubleshoot, as IE10 is still in beta.

Comment: Strictly speaking, the `encodeURIComponent` calls should be unnecessary, since jQuery will do that for you.

Comment: was using it without, doesn't fix anything.

Comment: compare console inspection of request to IE9 or IE8 view of same and see what differences are. Also add error handler to $.ajax. `"not working"` isn't a lot of info to work from

Comment: I can see the problem in my code (that do not use JSON code, but used 'object.varible = value'), and other people can repro.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
data: {email:email, password:pass}
```

should be

```
data: {"email":email, "password":pass}
```

You are passing the value of the variables as the key so if your server-side resource is expecting `email` it is actually seeing the value of that variable `encodeURIComponent($("#loginemail").val())`.

This is likely not an IE10 issue, this shouldn't work as written in any browser.

**Update**

This answer may no longer be applicable due to bug fixes in IE 10.

Please disregard this answer it is wrong and cannot be deleted due to being accepted.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/#example-1
$.post("test.php", { name: "John", time: "2pm" } );

Comment: email and pass would work if you didn't name a variable email and pass.  So if you don't put it in quotes the key will be the value of that variable.

Comment: Gotcha, thing is though, you can't type {email,pass}, can you?

Comment: No but this is a valid object literal `{"email":email, "password":pass}`, so code it exactly like that.  And as a correction this is issue is only with the email one.  Your password should work as is.  I know what you mean by the JQuery doc but it works just as well as I wrote it above.

Comment: Works on ie9, must be a bug. Good advice anyways though.

Comment: Keys in Javascript object literals can be unquoted providing they are not reserved words. Neither `email` nor `password` is reserved. Therefore the problem with IE10 must lie elsewhere - not immediately obvious what it might be.

Comment: That said, [this page](http://www.javascripter.net/faq/reserved.htm) recommends avoiding `password` (and many other non-reserved words).

Comment: This is still an issue with IE10 RTM which i'm using now.  Infact I couldn't post this comment in IE10 standard mode and had to switch to IE9 mode!

Comment: @AndrewHarry I'm having the same problem here. I had to force my site into IE9 mode to keep it working.. :-/

Comment: Same problem here.  IE 10 tries to download json post.

Comment: Why is this wrong? At the time a fresh copy of internet explorer and jquery would cause this issue. I believe IE10 was barely out the door though, so they could have squashed the bug making your answer irrelevant I suppose. What answer would you propose as the right one?

Comment: @kelton52 I re-updated it to state that it may no longer be applicable instead of 'wrong'.

Answer (score 3):

Can't fix @jQuery bug tracker: [AJAX Post on IE10 / Windows 8](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/12790)

Answer (score 0):

After deep debuggind I found a workaround for IE10 AJAX POST Bug:

do not use POST with GET.

```
$.post("Page.aspx?action=edit",a,function(data) {dataRow[0]=data; GoToShowMode(row)});
```

change to

```
a.action=edit;
$.post("Page.aspx",a,function(data) {dataRow[0]=data; GoToShowMode(row)});
```

Answer (score 0):

IE-10 does not work data serialize => **$(this).serialize()**

```
 $('#formLogin').submit(function () {

        $.ajax({
            url: this.action,
            type: this.method,
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            cache: false,
            success: function (data) {

                var val1 = "";
                var val2 = "";

                $.map(data, function (item) {
                    val1 = item.success;
                    val2 = item.URL;
                });

                if (data[0].messageCode == "success") {
                    GoGO(data[0].URL);
                }
                else {
                    alert(data[0].message);
                }
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
```

For this you can use this line on _layOut.chtml before metatag. So, IE-10 works just like IE-9.

```
  <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=9" >
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: http://code.gishan.net/code/solution-to-ie10-ajax-problem
Works for me. This is a known issue of IE10.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem with IE 10 (10.0.9200.16521) on Win7 x64 SP1.
I've solved the problem simply by using a newer version of jQuery (1.9.1 in place of 1.8.3)