# Ajax on IE10 don't send cookies

Tags: ajax, internet-explorer, jquery, cookies

Since IE10 has installed on my Windows 7 box, it is impossible to login into my application...
It was OK with IE9 and it still OK with FF and Chrome.

The problem is that session cookies (jsession id) are not send by IE when doing ajax request (POST or GET).

I've seen on SO many trouble with IE10 and cookies but no one can applied to my problem :
[IE10 User-Agent causes ASP.Net to not send back Set-Cookie (IE10 not setting cookies)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6983732/ie10-user-agent-causes-asp-net-to-not-send-back-set-cookie-ie10-not-setting-coo)
[jquery ajax $.post not working IE10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11235613/jquery-ajax-post-not-working-ie10)
[IE10 sharing cookies across subdomains by default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15115917/ie10-sharing-cookies-across-subdomains-by-deafult)

I precise that I'm not crossdomain. I use a Jasig/CAS for authentication and CAS cookies nor session cookies are send by ajax request.
Ajax request are send via JQuery (last version).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

### EDIT1:

I tried all IE security options and the last do not track without success.

### EDIT2:

I try Google Chrome Frame into my IE10 with adding  but nothing better.

Comment: Not sure if this is your problem at all, but I had something like this with a _ (underscore) in a subdomain name, and that caused no end of problems with IE and cookies. Removing the _ from the domain name fixed it. You didn't specify a domain, so I have no idea if that could be it...

Comment: I'm in test. So my domain name is localhost. With no _. I try also in a real environment (https://integ.clouderial.com) and the problem is the same.

Comment: @MarkOrmston : here you will find a very post explaining why _ is not supported by IE : http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2009/08/20/wininet-ie-cookie-internals-faq.aspx?PageIndex=5#comments

Comment: I opened a ticket on MS connect : https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/783147/ie10-redirect-on-ajax-request-not-always-followed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found what happens, and it can be usefull for others. @Mark Ormston was not so far :
Cookies set with path /cas are send by IE10 to URL beginings with /cas-services

In my case /cas and /cas-services are not in the same WebApp and each have its own JSESSIONID. Sending JSESSIONID created for /cas to /cas-services lead to the problem describe above.

To correct, I simply rename /cas-services with /app-services (I guess that everything not beginning with /cas should work).

JM.

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar problem and just added to the Web.Config in IIS cookieless="UseCookies" in the Authentication section.